# Applet is not showing in Browser

Tags: java, swing, applet

Following is my Java code. I compiled in to the class extension and attached to my HTML file. both HTML file and class files are located in the same directory. But the problem is that when I run it, the browser doesnt show anything. What is wrong with this code:

HTML Code:

```html
<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
<applet code = "HelloApplet.class" width="150" height="100">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloApplet extends JApplet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello World", 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error messages or exceptions? Is java enabled in your web browser?

Comment: javac compilation was successful thats why class file generated. No errors.

Comment: Applets are dead technology better switch to javascript(p5.js)

Comment: Which browser are you using? Most browsers no longer support applets.

Comment: @afzaal_ikram To ensure java is working correctly in your browser please follow the instruction of [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-wont-Java-Applets-run-in-my-web-browser) thread